# Mongo atlas error while connecting on digitalocean

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, digital-ocean

I edited the `mongodb.conf`, enabled the auth and inseting on bind_ip the ip of my droplet.

When I tried to connect to `mongo --host XXXX` it connects but can not find my users or database. for example:

$ mongo --host
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connectingto:mongodb://hostXXXX:27017/
MongoDB server version:3.6.3

> db.system.users.find()
> Error:error:{
> "ok":0
> "errmsg":"not authorized on test to execute command {find:"system.users", filter {}, $db: "test"},
> "code":13,
> "codeName":"Unauthorized"
> }

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of MongoDB there will be no `system.users` collection in the 'test' database, all user credential information is stored in the 'admin' database.

Atlas also restricts access to user credential information, so you probably won't be able to query that collection either.

If you need to find out about the current user, you can use the `connectionStatus` database command.

If you need to list or manage users programatically, you might find the [API](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/database-users/#database-users) useful.

Comment: Got it @Joe very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: But the thing is when I try to connect my cluster I can't because comes a warning saying shell and server versions do not match but they do. The thing is my mongo shell and server are 3.6 but my cluster is 4.2 is that where the problem is?